# Loopbackjs: Switch DB in datasource based on request origin

Tags: javascript, backend, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

**I need to switch the database in loopback datasource based on the request origin**

eg. If i make a request from **`xyz.domain.com`** I need to select **`xyz`**  database for the datasource (we are using wildcard subdomain on frontend so there will be multiple such subdomains).

I tried building middleware which extracts the subdomain from every request origin and sets the database for the datasource. Now the problem is after few simultaneous requests, loopback server breaks with **"too many connections"** error (may be because it's creating new connection thread on every request)

(I am using my-sql connector for datasource )

Following is my middleware code

```js
'use strict';

const DataSource = require('loopback-datasource-juggler').DataSource;
const app = require('../../server/server.js');
const getSubdomain = require('../middlewares/getSubdomain.js');

module.exports = function() {
  return function datasourceSelector(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path !== '/api/check-realm') {
      let subdomain = getSubdomain(req); // this will get me subdomain from request origin

      let dataSource = new DataSource({
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 3306,
        'database': subdomain ? subdomain[1] || 'default' : 'default',
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'user',
        'name': 'mysqlDS',
        'connector': 'mysql'
      }); // This creates new datasource on every request with appropriate database

      let models = app.models();

      models.forEach(function(model) {
        if (model.modelName !== 'Email') {
          model.attachTo(dataSource);
        }
      }); // here I am attaching all models to the newly created datasource.

      app.dataSource("mysqlDS", dataSource);

    }
    next();
  };
};
```

Other approaches to achieve this can also be helpful.

Comment: Maybe using `app.datasources` instead creating new datasource fixes the problem

Comment: But how can I change the DB name if I use `app.datasoures` directly

Answer (score 0):

`app.datasources` contains all datasources you define in the application.

For example :

//datasources.json

```
{
  "memo": {
    "name": "memo",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "admin": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test_db",
    "password": "",
    "name": "admin",
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
```

Then in your code check for subdomain and :

```
...
if (subdomain === 'admin'){
   models.forEach(function(model) {
        if (model.modelName !== 'Email') {
          model.attachTo(app.datasources.admin);
        }
      });
}
...
```